# Linux: who is listening on tcp port 22?

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, openbmc, dropbear

I have a AST2600 evb board. After power on (w/ RJ45 connected), it boots into a OpenBMC kernel. From serial port, using `ip` command I can obtain its IP address. From my laptop, I can `ssh` into the board using account `root/0penBmc`:

```
bruin@gen81:/$ ssh root@192.168.6.132
root@192.168.6.132's password:
```

Then I want to find out which tcp ports are open. As there is no `ss`/`lsof`/`netstat` utilities, I `cat /proc/net/tcp`:

```
root@AMIfa7ba648f62e:/proc/net# cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode        
   0: 00000000:14EB 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   997        0 9565 1 0c202562 100 0 0 10 0
   1: 3500007F:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   997        0 9571 1 963c8114 100 0 0 10 0
```

The strange thing puzzled me is that that tcp port 22 is not listed in `/proc/net/tcp`, which suggests that no process is listening on tcp port 22. If this is true, how the ssh connection is established?

Btw, as tested using `ps`, it's the `dropbear` process who is handling the ssh connection, and the `dropbear` is spawned dynamically (i.e., if no ssh connection, no such process exist; if I made two ssh connection, two `dropbear` processes were spawned).

PS: as suggested by John in his reply, I added the `ss` utilities into the image, and it shows what I expected:

```
root@AMI8287361b9c6f:~# ss -antp
State            Recv-Q            Send-Q                                  Local Address:Port                                  Peer Address:Port
LISTEN           0                 0                                             0.0.0.0:5355                                       0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=239,fd=12))
LISTEN           0                 0                                           127.0.0.1:5900                                       0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("obmc-ikvm",pid=314,fd=5))
LISTEN           0                 0                                          127.0.0.53:53                                         0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=239,fd=17))
LISTEN           0                 0                                                   *:443                                              *:*                 users:(("bmcweb",pid=325,fd=3),("systemd",pid=1,fd=41))
LISTEN           0                 0                                                   *:5355                                             *:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=239,fd=14))
LISTEN           0                 0                                                   *:5900                                             *:*                 users:(("obmc-ikvm",pid=314,fd=6))
LISTEN           0                 0                                                   *:22                                               *:*                 users:(("systemd",pid=1,fd=49))
LISTEN           0                 0                                                   *:2200                                             *:*                 users:(("systemd",pid=1,fd=50))
ESTAB            0                 0                               [::ffff:192.168.6.89]:22                           [::ffff:192.168.6.98]:34906             users:(("dropbear",pid=485,fd=2),("dropbear",pid=485,fd=1),("dropbear",pid=485,fd=0),("systemd",pid=1,fd=20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

First, it is pretty straigt forward to add common tools/utitlies to an image.
It could be added (for local testing only) by adding a line

```
OBMC_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:append = " iproute2 iproute2-ss"
```

to the https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/master/meta-aspeed/conf/machine/evb-ast2600.conf file (or to your own testing/deveopment layer). Adding useful tools is often worth it.

Second, if you are using ipv6 you will need to check `/proc/net/tcp6`

Third, you can also look for a port by looking up the pid of your application `ps | grep <application name>`. Then reading the port used by that pid `cat /proc/<pid>/net/tcp`

Last, if you have any more question or these steps don't work. Please reach out to us on discord https://discord.com/invite/69Km47zH98 or Email https://lists.ozlabs.org/listinfo/openbmc (they are the preferred place to ask questions)

Comment: Thank you very much, @John. After adding those two packages, I can see LISTENING ports by using `ss -antp`. I put the output of the command in the PS section of my question post. What I also learnt from this is that, it seems that a process listening on ipv6 port can also accept ipv4 incoming connections! Thanks again!

Comment: Btw, `OBMC_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:append` is not working in my OpenBmc tree (it's an old one with `BB_VERSION` v1.42.0); `OBMC_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL_append` worked instead.